How do you stop InputField from expanding to show all text in the field?
I recently updated to Mathematica 14 and InputField now behaves differently. I want to paste large amounts of data into an input field, and I don't want the input field to automatically expand.
Sample Code
DynamicModule[{a},
 (*initial input*)
 a = "This is default text. Copy and paste it many time to see if the \
Input expands.";
 (*input field to play with it.*)
 Column@{
   InputField[Dynamic@a, String, FieldSize -> {{5, 50}, {3, 3}}],
   Dynamic[a]}
 ]


I hoped FieldSize might prevent the growth, but it does not. I tried Scrollbar in case it was an undocumented option, but it is not.

While waiting for a better answer, you could put the InputField inside a Pane.

Adding an ImageSize option to the InputField prevents it from growing. For example:
DynamicModule[{a},
 (* initial input *)
 a = "This is default text. Copy and paste it many time to see if the Input expands.";
 (* input field to play with it. *)
 Column @ {
   InputField[ 
     Dynamic @ a,
     String,
     FieldSize -> {{5, 50}, {3, 3}},
     ImageSize -> {Full, 100} (* <----- ADD THIS *)
   ],
   Dynamic[a]}
 ]


That worked perfectly. Thanks
